# Drop off folder and power automate

Tags: power-automate, drop-off-library

I have a power automate flow that takes a newly arrived email and puts it in a drop off library.

The files get put into the library but don't trigger the content rule for that library.

However if i manually click upload and browse to the file i can get it to process.

Is there anyway i can just get any file that is added to that drop off library to automatically check against the rules?